# Content Hub Date Time Field not displaying Time option

Tags: content-hub

I am using Sitecore Content Hub and in one of the Content Types we have defined the Field type Datetime Field:
[image]

However, last two days I observed that while selecting the date the time option does not appear. Previously date and time options were there with a calendar and clock.

[image]

Time options are missing. Anyone facing the same issue or any idea, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please check the below steps might help you?

1. You go to the page where this component consists of the member.
2. Then click on the "..." as shown below.

[image]

3. Then click on Edit.
4. Then go to the DateTime Field. Something like below and click on the settings icon.

[image]

5. Then you will get a pop-up for Format and other settings where you can change the format as below.

[image]

6. The output will look like below.

[image]

For more details [check here](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/40/content-hub/manage--adding-format-datetime-picker.html). Hope this will help.

**Note:** This works for DateTime and DateTime offset.

Comment: Thanks, @Nikhil for the update. Can you please elaborate the step 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Thank you so much for having a call on the Slack channel and its resolved my issue.

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat ,Always there to help the community and happy that the issue is resolved.